# lua-socket: unix domain sockets?

Tags: sockets, unix, lua

I'm using lua-socket 3.0rc1.3 (that comes with Ubuntu Trusty) and lua 5.1. I'm trying to listen on a unix domain socket, and the only example code I can find is [this](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-07/msg00460.html)

```
-- send stdin through unix socket
socket = require"socket"
socket.unix = require"socket.unix"
c = assert(socket.unix())
assert(c:connect("/tmp/foo"))
while 1 do
    local l = io.read()
    assert(c:send(l .. "\n"))
end
```

Problem is, when I try and `connect()` I get "no such file or directory" - how do I create that socket in the first place? `mkfifo /tmp/foo` which someone recommended me gets me a "connection refused" error instead (I don't think a fifo is the same thing as a domain socket?).

Is there any minimal working example out there of using luasocket on a unix domain socket?

**EDIT: from Paul's solution, here's a MWE if anyone's interested**

```
libsocket = require "socket"
libunix = require "socket.unix"
socket = assert(libunix())
SOCKET="/tmp/socket"
assert(socket:bind(SOCKET))
assert(socket:listen())
conn = assert(socket:accept())
while 1 do
    data=assert(conn:receive())
    print("Got line: " .. data)
    conn:send("echo: " .. data .. "\n")
    if data == "." then conn:close() return end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can't create that socket using mkfifo (or any command) as it will be created by the (listening) server. There is an example listed on the same page you referenced, but it may be difficult to find:

```
sock, err = s:listen([backlog|_32_])
sock, err = s:bind(path)
client_conection, err = s:accept()
```

Basically, you create the server the same way you'd do it for TCP, only instead of binding to an address/port, you bind to a path and then start accepting new connections on it.

Answer (score 3):

Although [luasocket](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/home.html) provides `socket.unix`, I don't recommend using it unless you're already using luasocket and want to avoid another dependency:

- It is not mentioned anywhere in the [documentation](http://w3.impa.br/%7Ediego/software/luasocket/reference.html).
- The code says "This module is just an example of how to extend LuaSocket with a new domain" ([unix.h](https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/5b18e475f38fcf28429b1cc4b17baee3b9793a62/src/unix.h#L7)).

Instead I recommend [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix), which has a well-documented [API](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/). Here's a simple example:

```
-- Send stdin through a Unix socket.
local socket = require("posix.sys.socket")
local unistd = require("posix.unistd")
local fd = assert(socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0))
assert(socket.connect(fd, {family = socket.AF_UNIX, path = "/tmp/foo"}))
while true do
    local line = io.read()
    if not line then
        break
    end
    line = line .. "\n"
    local i = 1
    while i < #line do
        i = assert(socket.send(fd, line:sub(i)))
    end
end
unistd.close(fd)
```

Some other alternatives with explicit support for Unix sockets:

- [cqueues](http://25thandclement.com/%7Ewilliam/projects/cqueues.html)
- [lua-http](https://daurnimator.github.io/lua-http/0.3/) (depends on cqueues)