# Lua, how to read from unix file socket

Tags: sockets, unix, lua, unix-socket, luasocket

i am realy struggling to connect and read from a existing unix file socket.

the socket exist, is Mode +rwx and should return a json oneliner (without newline).

(i have no Problem to read the socket on debian based systems like `ncat -U /run/fastd.supernode.sock`)

While i try to solve it on a embedded device TP-Link841v11-ND Mips (Fastd Socket on an OpenWRT / LEDE Router from TP Link) mainly only lua (and luasocket) is available.
i come so far

```
$ lua
> socket = require"socket"
> socket.unix = require"socket.unix"
> getme = socket.unix("/var/run/fastd.mesh_vpn.socket")
> print(getme:receive())
stdin:1: calling 'receive' on bad self (unix{client} expected, got userdata)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'receive'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

**solution, for those who have similar problems**

(as described here https://forum.freifunk.net/t/connect-fastd-socket-on-tp841v11-fastd-statistiken/13499 )

(you need to reconnect each time you wanna read socket)

```
$ lua
> require "socket"
> require "socket.unix"
> c = socket.unix()
> c:connect("/var/run/fastd.mesh_vpn.socket")
> print(c:receive())
```

Comment: Replace first two line with a single `unix = require 'socket.unix'`, and `getme=unix"/var/run...sock"`

Comment: may be you need call connect method. e.g. `s=socket.unix();s:connect('path here')`? Never try this socket type.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing several commands; see the complete example in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240830/lua-socket-unix-domain-sockets/30243020#30243020) or [this maillist discussion](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-07/msg00493.html) for further details.

Comment: yes, i saw this - but there they deal with writing into a socket and that confused a lot - but thx nevertheless .. now i break this down to a bare minimum

Comment: I recommend using luaposix instead — see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65569899/148195) to a similar question.